# Why does natbib conflict with sbc.bst?

Tags: natbib

I'm always loading the package sbc-template. When I load `natbib` and use bibliography style `apalike`, no problem; when I use style `sbc` instead, compilation crashes. How to fix this? `Apalike` is pretty OK to me, but I unfortunately need to submit the paper with bibliography style `sbc` ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{sbc-template}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage{natbib}    
\sloppy    
\begin{document}    
\section{Section}
\cite{author2013test}

\bibliographystyle{sbc}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

URL for template and style:

http://www.sbc.org.br/documentos-da-sbc/summary/169-templates-para-artigos-e-capitulos-de-livros/878-modelosparapublicaodeartigos

Sample bib file:

```
@BOOK{author2013test,
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  year = {2013},
  author = {Author}
}
```

Ps: I'm sorry if it *looks* too much... I don't know to how to (or if possible to) upload a MWE with all files needed (beginner in the forum here :)

Comment: `sbc-template` redefines `\@lbibitem`, `\thebibliography`, and this conflicts with `natbib`. Moreover, the package loads the `caption2` and `times` packages, and is in general quite outdated.

Comment: Your MWE is just right, you made available everything needed. As mafp points out, any class that modifies something in bibliography with be incompatible with `natbib`, unless the class author thought about it and made there a part to be used when `natbib` is loaded. The problem is that most class authors don't do that :(

Answer (score 3):

`sbc-template.sty` redefines `\@lbibitem` and `\thebibliography`, and this conflicts with `natbib`. Moreover, a bibliography style has to be compatible with `natbib` to use advanced features, and unfortunately, `sbc.bst` is not one of them. Finally, `sbc-template.sty` loads the `caption2` and `times` packages, which are really outdated, so I would not recommend using this package.

However, if you can relinquish the nice features of `natbib` like `\citeauthor{...}`, you can make your document compile by cutting back to a numbered `natbib` style with the `numbers` option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{sbc-template}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\cite{StGu92}

\bibliographystyle{sbc}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]