# Left aligning LaTeX bibliography display

Tags: bibliographies

I have problem on how to make the bibliography items left-aligned.

My current bibliography output is below:

[image]

```
@misc{Steven,
  author = {{Berkeley - School of Information}},
  title = {{Steven Weber}},
  howpublished = "\url{https://www.ischool.berkeley.edu/people/steven-weber/}",
  year = {2019}, 
  note = "[Online; acessado em 25-fev-2019]"
}

@misc{AnnaLee,
  author = {{Berkeley - School of Information}},
  title = {{AnnaLee Saxenian}},
  howpublished = "\url{https://www.ischool.berkeley.edu/people/AnnaLee-Saxenian/}",
  year = {2019}, 
  note = "[Online; acessado em 25-fev-2019]"
}
```

As you can see, the reference item code is currently right-aligned, and I need it to be left-aligned. Any idea on how to achieve that?

My current code for the bibliography is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,table,border=2mm,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{sbc-template}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}     
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{label = Passo \arabic*:}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sbc-template}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not include code as image, we can not copy it and test it on our computers. In your case please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: What does the file `sbc-template.sty` contain? Is it available online?

Comment: @Mico it seems come from http://www.sbc.org.br/documentos-da-sbc/summary/169-templates-para-artigos-e-capitulos-de-livros/878-modelosparapublicaodeartigos (see the old URL displayed in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98982/132405, before my edit, currently in queue for peer review)

Comment: @Mico The old URL looks like this (archived by archive.org): https://web.archive.org/web/20140701053656/http://www.sbc.org.br/index.php?option=com_jdownloads&Itemid=195&task=view.download&catid=32&cid=38 so I'm confident the new correct URL is http://www.sbc.org.br/documentos-da-sbc/summary/169-templates-para-artigos-e-capitulos-de-livros/878-modelosparapublicaodeartigos

Comment: @quark67 - Thanks. (Aside: I've gone ahead and "approved" your edit of the earlier posting.) Let's wait and see if the OP is willing to provide some additional highly useful pieces of information, such as the bibliography style that's in use. For all we know, the style *might* be `sbc`, but it might just as well be some other bib style.

Comment: Please check the link I gave you in the first comment: we need an compilabe tex code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` building the bibliography in your shown image. If your used package `sbc-template` is relevant for your issue please add a link to it into your question!

Answer (score 1):

The `sbc` package has a strange redefinition of `thebibliography`, undoing it partially:

```
\documentclass[tikz,table,border=2mm,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{sbc-template}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}     
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{label = Passo \arabic*:}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            %% changed!
%               \itemindent -\leftmargin
               \itemsep 6pt
            %%%%%%%%%%%
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

test

\nocite{*}

{
\RaggedRight
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{sbc-template}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]